# Problems creating a mobile first database

Tags: json, ibm-cloud, hybrid-mobile-app

I’m experiencing problems with the mobile hybrid app on Bluemix. I’ve created a new app twice to make sure. The mobile data service reports that it ‘cannot get storage’ when I access the Manage Data tab. When I try to import json data it fails. It is the identical json data file that I import into an existing mobile hybrid app.

I have two customer facing apps to make ( they need iOS and Android versions ) - please can you advise me if it is still possible to drag and drop static json data files onto the mobile database?

Also, the link 'For more information about the file formats you can import, see importing data into the mobile data service' is broken.

Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /"https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/

If this is not the best way to build native apps for iOS and Android on Bluemix, please let me know.

Comment: Could you describe how you created the app, what steps were involved and what services? Are you using the "MobileFirst Services Starter" boilerplate?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Mobile: iOS, Android, Hybrid starter. I've used it successfully in the past. I've tried again just now, and see the same thing. Create the app, open the mobile data service, click the manage data tab, and drag and drop a json file.

Comment: Sample file: [{
    "disruptionRange": "1",
    "scannerWidth": "10",
    "disruptionTime": "30",
    "conference": "conf",
    "primaryColor": "",
    "secondaryColor": ""
}] ( works on apps I made before the past few days )

Answer (score 1):

We identified an issue with the Mobile Data Service earlier today that has just been fixed. Please let me know if you still experience this problem and apologies for any inconvenience this has caused.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the cloudant or mongolab for your datastorage requirement.

1.Take the Mobile cloud boilerplate and get the security and app id

2.Take Mongo or cloudant as DB and bind it with your mobile application just created

3.In the mobile client and server code, initialize with IBMBluemix.jar initialization functions

4.Now you are ready to read/write data to the database.

Hope this helps.You can refer a sample code in the git below:

If this does not help, then as henry asked, pls. provide more details. https://github.com/RajeshJeyapaul/Beacons-Messenger

video: https://youtu.be/Gn03yIZiCAc